# Flexbox layout structure overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a flexbox layout using the following HTML and CSS styling.
I would like the header and footer to be always visible as they are right now and also the main content to have the same size always.

As I have it right now, the main content is displayed correctly, but the side divs are being scrolled too when I scroll the main content. I would like to scroll only inside the main content div (orange one), ocuppying the whole height (even if it doesn't have enough characters to fill it), I don't want to scroll outside the main content div.

In other words, I would like to scroll only tha main content div (orange one) without the header, sidenavs and footer to be scrolled too.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

header {
    background-color: lightcoral;
    width: 100%;
    align-self: flex-start;
}

main {
    background-color: lightcyan;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

footer {
    background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    width: 100%;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.flex-column-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.col1 {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.col2 {
    flex-grow: 4;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    padding: 20px;
}

.col3 {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: lightpink;
}

.content {
    background-color: lightsalmon;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flexbox Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <header>This is a header</header>
        <main>
            This is the main content
            <div class="flex-column-container">
                <div class="col1">
                    Left sidenav
                </div>
                <div class="col2">
                    Main
                    <div class="content">
                        Main content div.
                        <br>
                        I want this div to occupy the remaining height
                        without expanding the flexbox layout. I would
                        like the div to have an overflow when the content
                        is bigger than the layout space available.
                        I don't want the sidenavs to be scrolled too as they
                        scroll right now.
                        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                        End of this section.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                    Right sidenav
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>This is the footer</footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You can set [position: sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) on your side navs to give the appearance of the main content scrolling.

I added comments to the CSS to show what I changed.

Another helpful link from [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/)

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

header {
    background-color: lightcoral;
    width: 100%;
    align-self: flex-start;
}

main {
    background-color: lightcyan;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

footer {
    background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    width: 100%;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.flex-column-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    /* added to make sure sticky elements have a parent position */
    position: relative;
}

.col1 {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: lightgray;
    /* add sticky and top to stop them from scrolling */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.col2 {
    flex-grow: 4;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    padding: 20px;
}

.col3 {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: lightpink;
    /* add sticky and top to stop them from scrolling */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.content {
    background-color: lightsalmon;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flexbox Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <header>This is a header</header>
        <main>
            This is the main content
            <div class="flex-column-container">
                <div class="col1">
                    Left sidenav
                </div>
                <div class="col2">
                    Main
                    <div class="content">
                        Main content div.
                        <br>
                        I want this div to occupy the remaining height
                        without expanding the flexbox layout. I would
                        like the div to have an overflow when the content
                        is bigger than the layout space available.
                        I don't want the sidenavs to be scrolled too as they
                        scroll right now.
                        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                        End of this section.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                    Right sidenav
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>This is the footer</footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is much likely what I wanted :D. Is there a way of making the orange div only the height of the size between the header and footer and scroll the text inside of it? If there is not, no worries your answer already helped me a lot!